# appendChild inside a newly created div

Tags: javascript, dom

I can't understand why I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
//create new div element, append it to the body, give it an ID and a Class.
const container_clause_1 = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(container_clause_1);
container_clause_1.setAttribute("id", "container_clause_1");
container_clause_1.classList.add("cc1");

console.log(container_clause_1);
//returns <div id="container_clause_1" class="cc1></div>"

const cClause1 = document.getElementById("container_clause_1");

console.log(cClause1);
//returns <div id="container_clause_1" class="cc1></div>"

const right_clause_1 = document.createElement("div");
console.log(right_clause_1); //returns <div></div>

document.cClause1.appendChild(right_clause_1); //Error occurs here!
```

I don't understand what is undefined in this situation.  `cClause1` is define.  `right_clause_1` is also defined.  Granted, it's an empty div at this point, but that is what I am trying to do - add the div and then I can add the class and id, etc.

Also, I don't see any typos.

Also, if I replace `document.cClause1.appendChild(right_clause_1);`
with `document.body.appendChild(right_clause_1);` it works fine.  Except that I don't want it inside the body, but rather, inside the container_clause_1 div.

I can't use JQuery for this.  "Why not" is not really germane to the question.  I have my reasons.  Just understand that I can't use JQuery.

---

Well that was so obvious - after everyone started pointing out what I did wrong!  Thanks for the answers!

Just another thing that this pointed out to me:

I can eliminate the variable `cClause` and just use `container_clause_1`

so my code is shorter!

```
const container_clause_1 = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(container_clause_1);
container_clause_1.setAttribute("id", "container_clause_1");
container_clause_1.classList.add("cc1");

const right_clause_1 = document.createElement("div");
container_clause_1.appendChild(right_clause_1);
right_clause_1.setAttribute("id", "right_clause_1");
right_clause_1.classList.add("r1");
```

Comment: There is no `cClause1` on `document`. Just use `cClause1` without the `document.`.

Comment: Try document.body.cClause1.appendChild(right_clause_1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have "document." in this line?

```
document.cClause1.appendChild(right_clause_1);
```

Surely you only need:

```
cClause1.appendChild(right_clause_1);
```

Comment: Derp!  Geez, i did't see what i did!  of course that is correct!  @Mike McCaughan also said that answer in his comment.  Thanks for the superfast answers